# Handling node http.Server#listen() error with callback

Tags: node.js

I am trying to handle nodejs http.Server listen error with callback. But the following example will throw.

If I wrap the `server.listen` function into a `try ... catch` it works and the callback get called with the error.

Can You please enlighten me, why it doesn't work without `try ... catch`?
Is there any better way to catch the listen error?

```
const { createServer } = require('http')

function build(handler, callback) {
  const server = createServer((req, res) => handler)

  // this will throw RangeError
  server.listen(99999, function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err, null)
    return callback(null, server)
  })
})
```

*Edit:* node version: 10.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general node will throw a range error if provided function arguments are out of expected range, you can try/catch in your build function like so and handle it there

```
function build(handler, callback) {
    try {
      const server = createServer(handler);

      // this will throw RangeError
      server.listen(99999, function (err) {
        callback(err, server);
      });
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof RangeError) {
            // handle your special range rrrors
        } else {
            // handle all your other errors
        }
    }

};
```

also you can pass your handle directly to the createServer, and for you error callback you don't need to return the result of your callback

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I still confused about `why it throws` even if the error in the listen function handled with callback. Eg normally you can use the callbacks to catch errors. But in this particular case instead of passing the error to the callback and let me handle it, it omits the callback and thorws anyway.

Comment: range error is not returned in node, node throws it along with many other so you can handle them gracefully using try/catch

Comment: Ahh, it is clear now. So i should expect this in every case when node throws [system errors](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)?

Answer (score 4):

Answered for Node 13:

If you are expecting errors in the callback, I think this is incorrect. I think specifically in this case, the callback is not called if there is an error.

The key is to instead listen for the 'error' event to be triggered:

```js
async function build(handler, callback) {
  const server = createServer((req, res) => handler);

  try {
    let startFinished = false;
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      server.listen(3000, () => {
        if (!startFinished) {
          startFinished = true;
          resolve();
        }
      });
      server.once('error', (err) => {
        if (!startFinished) {
          startFinished = true;
          console.log(
            'There was an error starting the server in the error listener:',
            err
          );
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
    return callback(null, server);
  } catch (e) {
    // Do with the error e as you see fit
    console.log('There was an error starting the server:', e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer - this helped me a lot. I wanted to point out that there's an edge case where an error happens after the server was started - in such a case you are rejecting a resolved promise. You should keep some internal state like `isFinished` which is set to true whenever the promise resolves or rejects.

Comment: Good point @RyanWheale. I added a variable to track the state.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Charley's answer the best. Allyraza's answer caught the error, but directly to the console as well. Charley's answer bugged me though with the extra variable "startFinished". I found I could avoid this and have the best of both worlds by using err appropriately.

```
async function build(handler, callback) {
  // Creating http Server
  const server = http.createServer(handler);

  // The key is to instead listen for the 'error' event to be triggered:
  // listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // Listening to http Server
      server.listen(3000, (err) => {

        if (!err)
          resolve();
      });
      server.once('error', ( err ) => {

        if (err) {
          //console.log( 'There was an error starting the server in the error listener:', err);
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });

    // All good
    return callback(null, server);

  } catch (e) {

    // Return to caller any errors
    // console.log('There was an error starting the server:', e );
    return callback(e, server);
  }
}

// Setting up PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

build(requestListener, (e, server) => {
  if (e) {
    console.log(`startServer failed: ${ e }` );
  } else {
    console.log(`Started server. Listening on PORT: ${ PORT }...` );
  }
});
```